Swift pressesBegan no longer works iOS 18?
Previously this code would trigger fine on pressesBegan in iOS 17, but no longer works in iOS 18. How can I start capturing pressesBegan in iOS 18?
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        KeyBoardView()
    }
}

//To Use in SwiftUI
struct KeyBoardView: UIViewRepresentable{
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> KeyEventView {
    KeyEventView()
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: KeyEventView, context: Context) {
  }

  class KeyEventView: UIView {
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) 
    {
      print("test")
    }
  }
}


@Sweeper Did you use a keyboard? It works fine in 17.4 for me with a keyboard

@Sweeper ah I've never gotten pressesBegan to work on the simulator, you have to use a physical device unfortunately.

Well that's interesting, because pressesBegan does work on a simulator in a UIViewController, and it also works in a UIView if that view is the first responder. Does putting it in a UIViewController also work on a real device?

@Sweeper Thank you so much! Using UIViewController to handle it and setting it as first responder fixes it! Off to push out my app patch :)

@Sweeper Dang actually in a small test app it works, but once the swiftui view gets more complex it stops working

Well you will need to produce a [mcve] for that.

@Sweeper yeah, working on it, seems sort of random at the moment, I'll tag you if I can figure it
